# How to set up a local Graphhoper server on Ubuntu

Tags: graphhopper

I have already installed an OSRM server - just the backend. And I have used it with Leaflet to calculate routes. I want to test other services so I came across Graphhoper.

Contrary to OSRM I can't find a manual on how to set up a local server. I want to have just the backend of Graphhoper that would do the calculations and pass them to Leaflet. My motivation for the local server is also the fact that in that case no API Key would be needed.

Is it even possible to install *only* the backend of Graphhoper? Or am I understanding something wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a JVM installed you need to run two commands:

```
wget https://graphhopper.com/public/releases/graphhopper-web-3.0.jar https://raw.githubusercontent.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/3.x/config-example.yml http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany/berlin-latest.osm.pbf

java -Ddw.graphhopper.datareader.file=berlin-latest.osm.pbf -jar *.jar server config-example.yml
```

The documentation is here: https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper#get-started